# Getting 404 errors with .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm having trouble with a redirect .htaccess file.

I've updated a garage website but we seem to be getting some traffic to an old, non existent HTML page. I think it may have been bookmarked. The new version is in PHP.
I cannot get .htaccess file to redirect to the new php page. I just seem to get a 404 error (interestingly, with the old favicon).
Can anyone help please?

This is what I have so far:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index\.html index.php [NC,R]
Redirect 301 /page_zz3247638.html http://www.new-site.co.uk/Repair.php
#Force www:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new-site.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-site.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

As you can see the .htaccess file redirects from non-www to www also.
Thanks
Ali

Comment: Are you really certain that the target script file name is `Repair.php` and not `repair.php`? Remember that file systems in server environments usually are case sensitive, since they typically are Linux based, so "unixoid".

Answer (score 0):

Your first redirect does not have `L` flag. Try this.

`Redirect ^page_zz3247638.html$ http://www.new-site.co.uk/Repair.php [R=301,L]`

`L` means it's the last rule Apache has to execute. All the next rules are omitted.